# Convert C++ string to a char array, while encoding it in UCS2 (or utf-8)

Tags: c++, unicode, icu, ucs2

Take the following string

```
std::string input = "Test ";
```

The UCS2 representation of this string in hex is

> 0x00 0x54 0x00 0x65 0x00 0x73 0x00 0x74 0x00 0x20 0xd8 0x3d 0xde 0x01

Because the input string needs additional characters to store the unicode representation of the smiley. Is there an easy way to convert this string into a char array with the values as above? I'm looking at the ICU library and boost locale, and while they seem to handle translating from 1 encoding to another I don't see any easily available APIs to convert from string to char*. Note that I say "UCS2" but my underlying c++17 string is actually in utf-8.

I could write my own api to start from the first character and keep pushing to a char* array byte by byte until I encounter a char who's ascii value is > 127, then restart the encoding with 2 bytes instead of the 1. I need to do a potential double pass because I don't know if the input string will have characters that cannot be coded in ansi.

But maybe there's a native way (or even a 3rd party lib) that does it already?

Comment: ucs2 and utf8 are entirely different things, which one you want?

Comment: Have you tried `std::string input = u8"Test ";` (UTF-8) or `std::u16string input = u"Test ";` (UTF-16) or `std::wstring input = L"Test ";` (UTF-16 or UTF-32 depending on platform) yet?  Have you looked at `std::wstring_convert` yet? Once you have the string data encoded in whatever UTF you want, what is stopping you from simply `memcpy()`'ing the raw bytes of that encoding as-is into your `char` buffer?  Oh, and FYI, what you describe is not UCS-2, it is UTF-16.  UCS-2 can't handle Unicode codepoints outside of the BMP (U+0000..U+FFFF), such as `` (U+1F601).

Comment: @pm100 ucs2. I don't know how C++ represents that so I assumed I'd use utf-8 for it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau

`std::string s1 = u8"Test ";
    cout << s1 << endl;
    unsigned char *ch = new unsigned char(s1.size() + 1);
    
    memcpy(ch, s1.c_str(), s1.size());

    try{
    
    for(int i = 0; i < s1.size(); i++)
        cout << " 0x" << hex << (int)ch[i];
    }catch(std::exception &ex)
    {
        cout << "caught exe " << ex.what() << endl;
    }

    delete ch;
`

Test 
 0x54 0x65 0x73 0x74 0x20 0xf0 0x9f 0x98 0x81

I'm expecting "0x000x540x000x650x000x730x000x740x000x200xd80x3d0xde0x01"

Comment: `std::string s1 = u8"Test "; cout << s1 << endl;` will work just fine, provided your source file is saved as UTF-8, your compiler supports UTF-8 encoded source files, and your terminal supports UTF-8 output at runtime. `unsigned char *ch = new unsigned char(s1.size() + 1);` allocates a *single* `unsigned char` whose *value* is `s1.size() + 1`, it does not allocate an *array* of `s1.size() + 1` `unsigned char`s, use `new[]` instead. `memcpy(ch, s1.c_str(), s1.size());` is not copying the null terminator, even though you tried to allocate room for it.  `delete ch;` needs to be `delete[] ch;`

Comment: Consider using `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead of `new[]` directly.  But in any case, you are *expecting* UTF-16 encoded bytes to be output, but you are encoding the string to UTF-8 instead. Do you understand the difference between the byte representations of the various UTF encodings? I don't think you do. UTF-8 has a completely different byte representation than UTF-16 has.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ah, that's right. I whipped up the test code in a hurry and made a bunch of mistakes. So if my expected answer is in ucs2, how do I work to get  there?

Comment: Forget UCS-2, nobody uses it anymore. You want UTF-16 instead. They are NOT the same thing. As for the code, try this: `std::u16string s1 = u"Test "; using byte = unsigned char; size_t numbytes = s1.size() * sizeof(char16_t); unsigned char *ch = new byte[numbytes]; memcpy(ch, s1.c_str(), numbytes); for(int i = 0; i < numbytes; ++i) { cout << " 0x" << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(ch[i]); } delete[] ch;`

Comment: Alternatively: `std::u16string s1 = u"Test "; using byte = unsigned char; vector<byte> ch(s1.size() * sizeof(char16_t)); memcpy(ch.data(), s1.c_str(), ch.size()); for(byte b : ch) { cout << " 0x" << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(b); }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau

Thank you very much. I'm interfacing with an sms code api and it uses UCS2.

Comment: I seriously doubt it uses actual UCS-2, otherwise emojis could not be used at all.  UTF-16 is the successor to UCS-2, and is backwards compatible with UCS-2 for Unicode codepoints in the BMP.  It is only for higher codepoints that UCS-2 and UTF-16 differ.

Comment: Fair enough. I read the code and it looks like even though it is documented as UCS2 it's UCS16 because (from another website) UCS2 doesn't support emojis. Now, running your code I get the endianness swapped 0x54 0x00 0x65 0x00 0x73 0x00 0x74 0x00 0x20 0x00 0x3d 0xd8 0x01 0xde I'll have to swap them but should be doable

Comment: @RemyLebeau

I added the following code after your code (with the char array, not vector)

std::u16string wstr(&ch[0], &ch[0]+numbytes);

   std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>,char16_t> conv1;
   std::string u8str = conv1.to_bytes(wstr);

   cout << u8str << endl;

I get "Test =￘". Does this mean the text wasn't written as string correctly or was not displayed correctly?

Comment: @moffat_lal_p yes, UTF-16/32 suffer from endian, that is why there are "little endian" (UTF-16/32 LE) and "big endian" (UTF-16/32 BE) flavors defined. You need to know which flavor SMS is expecting, and which flavor your compiler uses, and then convert between them as needed. This is why UTF-16/32 is not ideal for transmission purposes. UTF-8 is usually preferred, and does not suffer from endian. But, not all SMS systems support UTF-8, sadly.

Comment: @moffat_lal_p `std::u16string wstr(&ch[0], &ch[0]+numbytes);` DOES NOT do what you think. It is iterating bytes, extending each byte as-is to `char16_t`, That will only work for ASCII characters in the 0x00-0x7F range. Since `ch` contains UTF-16 encoded bytes, you need to iterate in units of `char16_t` instead: `std::u16string wstr(reinterpret_cast<char16_t*>(ch), reinterpret_cast<char16_t*>(ch+numbytes));`. But what is wrong with simply using the original `std::u16string` that you used to populate `ch` from? `std::string u8str = conv1.to_bytes(s1);`

Comment: Good grief. I really need to brush up my C 101, I'm so out of touch with memory alignment and such with basic data structures. The code I presented to you was a sample. In reality these are 2 different functions - one to receive texts, other to send them. I'm having to bridge 3 different components, each of them using a different way of storing the same message - char*, string, json. And I use codecvt_utf8_utf16 which was deprecated in C++!7. There are talks of going to C++20 and so I'll have to do this all over again. You've saved me days of research and I greatly appreciate the help. Thanks!